# R.java is deleted

Tags: android, r.java-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R file is missing android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842611/r-file-is-missing-android)

Hello
The file R.java is deleted when i clicked on "clean"

How can i recreated it??

thank you

Comment: Possible Dupe 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536680/why-does-r-does-not-exist-error-come-in-android

Comment: Possible Dupe 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842611/r-file-is-missing-android

Comment: Possible Dupe 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619162/how-to-generate-r-java

Comment: Possible Dupe 4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757107/developing-for-android-in-eclipse-r-java-not-generating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build process will remake it for you.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, sometimes it gets into a tizzy and you need to delete then entire gen/ directory in order for a build to work again.

Answer (score 6):

jleedev... Another possibility is that you have an error in an xml file in which case the compiler cannot parse the xml file and will fail to generate a new R.java file. Usually there is a little red flag on the problematic child.

JAL