# How to access resource file from class which is not extending Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, constructor, resources, android-context

I have a class with **context passed in the constructor**:

```
public abstract class AbstractDbAdapter {
    protected Context context; 

    public AbstractDbAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;     
        String email = context.getString(R.string.my_email);
    }
```

It doesn't compile with the error at last string:

```
package R does not exist context.getString(R.string.my_email);
```

Package R definetly exists! I use the same call:

```
context.getString(R.string.my_email);
```

in other class which **extends Activity** without any problems. Moreover, I see strings:

```
public static final class string {
    ...
    public static final int my_email=0x7f06001e;
    ...
}
```

in R.java. What should I do to get my code working in the class not extending Activity!?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536680/why-does-r-does-not-exist-error-come-in-android: that might be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activities, and the AbstractDbAdapter must be in different packages.

You just need to import the `R` class.

```
import com.example.R;
```

Comment: You are right! Thanks a lot! But Netbeans compiler always ask me to add needed imports before this case...

Comment: Yes, Android resources are a little odd; the ...R package is dynamically build from the resources, and this doesn't really fit with traditional IDE concepts of java packages.